# Path aliases for Angular library project not wokring

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to implement an Angular library with ui elements. The library is a monorepo which then published like this

```
@lib/core
@lib/i18n
@lib/ui
```

The development is beeing done under Storybook.

This is my structure.

```
projects
    lib
        core
        i18n
        ui
tsconfig.json
```

Components inside ui directory have dependencies in the core and i18n directories.

The parent tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
      "paths": {
        "@lib/core": ["projects/lib/core/src/*"],
        "@lib/i18n": ["projects/lib/i18n"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

- i18n directory does not contain a src folder.

Files from i18n directory are resolved correctly and i can ctrl+click them (using phpstorm) to move to the files.

Files form @lib/core throw these errors during compilation

```
ERROR in /path/to/project/projects/lib/ui/src/lib/widgets/help/components/widget-button/cl-widget-button.component.ts
TS2307: Cannot find module '@lib/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Also the structure of core directory

[image: Also the structure of core directory]

public-api.ts is my entry point including all the exports

```
// index.ts
export * from './public-api.ts';
```

The reason i am using type aliases is to emulate the production like imports where all the packages will be installed through npm separately.

If i use the relative path (../../../../path/to/core) then everyting builds and runs as it should but in production this path does not exists, of course.

What i tryed:

- rootDirs typescript option without any luck.
- "@lib/core/*": ["projects/lib/core/src/*"], in paths without any luck.
- Place the paths options in a different tsconfig file, example inside ui/tsconfig.json without any luck. In fact in this case the i18n stoped working also.

I am starting to beleive that i can't make an alias of a stucture like that.

What am i missing here?

Comment: HI! Have you found a solution for this problem? If yes, could you please share it here? I just bumped into a similar one.

Comment: I managed to find a solution yes, i will try to explain it here in the next days thanks.

Comment: Hi how did you managed to make paths alias working for angular libraries ?

Answer (score 1):

I can provide my solution

1. In root `tsconfig.json` put this:

```
    "paths": {
      "@lib/core": [
        "dist/lib/core", // it depends on your library name
        "dist/core"
      ],
      ...
    }
```

2. Add command in `package.json` like this

```
"start:storybook": "ng build lib && ng serve storybook"
```